# Batch file creating 2 folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have made a batch file to create a single folder everyday for some files to be copied to it. But after scheduling it in Windows server 2003 it is creating 2 folders, one by date and another by day. Below is the script i have used:

```
mkdir %date:/=%
cd..
cd temp
copy *.* D:\Folder_name\%date:/=%
```

I don't know much about scripting and batch file creation. Need help!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why this question is tagged `powershell` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes to make a single directory.  Spaces split the term up if they are not quoted.

```
mkdir "%date:/=%"
cd..
cd temp
copy *.* "D:\Folder_name\%date:/=%"
```